# Matlab mex command for building armaMex_demo.cpp in Armadillo in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, mex, armadillo

I am having troubles mex-ing armaMex_demo_cpp in Armadillo (armadillo-8.500.1) in Windows with Matlab (2018a).

So far I am trying the command:

```
>> mex -LC:\Users\Test\Documents\Armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include\armadillo -LC:\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\gfortran -IC:\Users\Test\Documents\Armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include armaMex_demo.cpp
```

and get the error messages (truncated):

```
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017'.
Error using mex
armaMex_demo.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\random(31): error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\random(31): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before
identifier 'ARMA_USE_BLAS'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\random(31): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\random(31): error C2447: '{': missing function header
(old-style formal list?)
c:\users\test\documents\armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include\armadillo_bits/arma_rng_cxx11.hpp(28): error C2039: 'mt19937_64': is not a
member of 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\atomic(42): note: see declaration of 'std'
c:\users\test\documents\armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include\armadillo_bits/arma_rng_cxx11.hpp(28): error C3083: 'mt19937_64': the symbol
to the left of a '::' must be a type
c:\users\test\documents\armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include\armadillo_bits/arma_rng_cxx11.hpp(28): error C2039: 'result_type': is not a
member of 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\atomic(42): note: see declaration of 'std'
c:\users\test\documents\armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include\armadillo_bits/arma_rng_cxx11.hpp(28): error C3646: 'seed_type': unknown
override specifier
```

Does any one have any ideas of what I may be doing wrong here?

Anybody have a working mex command for building the mex file for armaMex_demo.cpp in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have something to do with how I am including/referencing to BLAS. I used to have the line '#define ARMA_USE_BLAS' uncommented in config.hpp. By leaving it commented I, with this mex command:

> > mex -LC:\Users\Test\Documents\Armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include\armadillo -LC:\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\gfortran -IC:\Users\Test\Documents\Armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include armaMex_demo.cpp

I only get this error:

Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017'.

Error using mex
armaMex_demo.cpp
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\mex_interface\armaMex_demo.cpp(44): error C2668: 'arma::size': ambiguous call to
overloaded function

c:\users\test\documents\armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\include\armadillo_bits/fn_size.hpp(38): note: could be 'const

arma::SizeMat
arma::size(const T1 &)'
        with
        [
            T1=arma::mat
        ]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\xutility(1654): note: or       'arma::uword
std::size(const _Container &)'
        with
        [
            _Container=arma::mat
        ]
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Armadillo\armadillo-8.500.1-mod_for_windows\mex_interface\armaMex_demo.cpp(44): note: while trying to match the argument list
'(arma::mat)'

Answer (score 0):

And by changing the line

if ( size(X) != size(Y) )

to

if ( X.size() != Y.size() )

in armaMex_demo.cpp

the mexing (and the mex call) works in Windows from Matlab.